# Telegram bot - KeyboardButton on CallbackQueryHandler (python)

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I'm trying to send custom keyboard(KeyboardButton) on inline button press handler(CallbackQueryHandler) in python - but no luck.

If I place the code that sends custom keyboard into /start handler, it works fine.

Any idea?

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import config
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram import KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, 
ReplyKeyboardRemove
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler

def start(bot, update):
  keyboard = []
  keyboard.append([InlineKeyboardButton(u'11', callback_data='1')])
  keyboard.append([InlineKeyboardButton(u'22', callback_data='2')])
  keyboard.append([InlineKeyboardButton(u'33', callback_data='3')])
  reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

  update.message.reply_text('Please choose:',  reply_markup=reply_markup)

def button(bot, update):
  query = update.callback_query
  keyboard = [[KeyboardButton('button1'), KeyboardButton('button2')]]
  reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
  bot.edit_message_text(text='some text',\
  chat_id=query.message.chat_id,\
  message_id=query.message.message_id,reply_markup=reply_markup)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  updater = Updater(config.token)
  updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
  updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
  updater.start_polling()
  updater.idle()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found the answer - using bot.edit_message_text() function edits the messsage associated with inline button, i.e. when we send message via above function, inline keyboards disappear and the new message takes it's place.
Instead, we should use like this,
    bot.send_message(query.message.chat_id, 'Some text', reply_markup=reply_markup)

Answer (score 0):

The logic that worked for me was the following:

```
def function_I_want_to_call(update, context):
(...)
InlineKeyboardButton('Text on UI', callback_data='function_I_want_to_call')
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(function_I_want_to_call))
```

Every time the user clicks on the button, it calls the function you want it.